Is the Ted-Ed Leprechaun's Magic Bag Unique?
Inspiration:

Ted Ed: This one weird trick will get you infinite gold - Dan Finkel
Codegolf Stack Exchange: Shift Right by Half a Trit - AlephSquirrel

Consider a Magic Bag which has the following properties:

Whenever a whole number of gold coins is placed into it, a larger whole number of gold coins may be taken out. (e.g. $f(x) > x$)
If the coins taken out are placed back in again, the resulting value will be three times the original. (e.g. $f(f(x)) = 3x$)
If more coins go in, more coins come out. (e.g. $x > y \rightarrow f(x) > f(y)$)
The bag only works on whole numbers of gold coins, you can't put pieces of coins in, and it will never produce pieces of a coin. (e.g. $x \in W$)

There is a function which has all of these properties (spoiler in case people want to work it out for themselves, but discovering it is not part of the puzzle):

 Represent the number of gold coins in ternary.
 If the leading digit is a 1, change it to a 2.
 If the leading digit is a 2, change it to a 1 and add a trailing 0.
 The result is the number of gold coins which can be taken out of the bag.

Is this the only function which has the properties required?

The answer is

 Yes, the function described in the question is the only such function.

To prove this, let's begin by

 looking at $f(1)$. This needs to be bigger than the input $1$, but $f(f(1))=3$, so $f(1)$ needs to be smaller than its image $3$. This leaves only one option for $f(1)$, namely $2$.The fact that $f(f(1))=3$ now means $f(2)=3$.

Before we move forward, let's make one small observation.

 If we run $n$ coins through the magic bag twice, we end up with $3n$ coins. What happens if we run those $n$ coins thrice instead? On one hand, the last step is putting $3n$ coins into the bag, so the answer should be $f(3n)$. But on the other hand, this process amounts to taking the result of the first round (that yielded $f(n)$ coins) and running it through the bag twice, which should triple the amount to $3f(n)$. This means $f(3n)=3f(n)$: in other words, tripling the input must triple the output.

There's a terser, mathematical way to phrase the same thing:

 Replacing $n$ with $f(n)$ in the equation $f(f(n))=3n$ gives $f(f(f(n)))=3f(n)$, but applying $f$ to both sides of $f(f(n))=3n$ gives $f(f(f(n)))=f(3n)$. Comparing these equations gives what we just derived above.

Anyway, using this fact, we can determine the images of

 All of the powers of $3$, and all the numbers that are twice a power of $3$. Indeed, $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=3$, so tripling the inputs over and over, we deduce $f(3^n)=2\cdot 3^n$ and $f(2\cdot 3^n)=3^{n+1}$. One can verify these match what we would expect from the given example function, although that's not necessary for the proof.

Next, it remains to fix the images of everything else. Start by looking at the numbers that lie

 between $3^n$ and $2\cdot 3^{n}$. There's exactly $3^n-1$ of them. Because $f$ is strictly increasing, they need to get mapped to the numbers lying between $f(3^n)=2\cdot 3^n$ and $f(2\cdot 3^n)=3^{n+1}$ in increasing order. There's exactly $3^n-1$ possible images as well, so there's only one way to match the values to their images, and since the function described already provides one such way to do it, this must be the only way.

Now what about the numbers between

 $2\cdot 3^n$ and $3^{n+1}$? Well, thanks to the previous paragraph, they are all of the form $f(k)$ for some $k$ lying between $3^n$ and $2\cdot 3^n$. Because of the equation $f(f(k))=3k$, this uniquely determines their images as well: the image of $f(k)$ image must be $3k$. We could do some complicated analysis to figure out exactly what this matching is, but we don't have to: we already have an example of a function that satisfies all the given constraints, and since we just saw the images are all uniquely determined by those constraints, $f$ has to match the given example.

This takes care of all numbers:

 every whole number that's not of the form $3^n$ or $2\cdot 3^n$ lies either between $3^n$ and $2\cdot 3^n$, or between $2\cdot 3^n$ and $3^{n+1}$ for some integer $n$ (depending on whether its leading digit in ternary is $1$ or $2$). So we're done!


Nicely proven! I find it interesting that the range $[3^n, 2 \cdot 3^n)$ shows up as a branching point in the proof of uniqueness - that condition corresponds exactly to the leading digit in the ternary representation of the value, which is a branch in the function as well.

So, I solved this question, but then I saw that it was pretty much the same as the one already written. But the question doesn't actually require us to find out the function(s), it only asks if there's only one or more, so here's another approach:

 Since $f(1), f(2)$ and $f(3)$ are trivial, let's say there are multiple possible functions that give the exact same results until $f(n)$. We can understand that none of the possible $x=f(n)$ numbers can be divisible by $3$, and $n$ was never a result of any $f(y)$ until then.  Also, all positive multiples of $3$ must show up once as a result. That means any $3k$ number must satisfy $f(m)=3k; m>=k$.  Besides, if $f(a+1) - f(a) > 3$, then so would be $f(f(a+1)) - f(f(a)) > 3$. So $f(a+1) - f(a) < 4$.  All the possible $x=f(n)$ numbers must be prime to $3$, and there must be no multiple of it in between $y=f(n-1)$ and $x=f(n)$. If $f(n-1) = 3r$, $f_1(n) = 3r+1$ and $f_2(n) = 3r+2$. Otherwise there aren't enough options. By extension, $f_2(n+1) = 3r+3$, but that means $f(r) = n-1$ and $f(r+1) = n$, which leads to a contradiction unless there's a unique solution.

